# How can I deploy a SharePoint Framework webpart with a Microsoft Graph API query as an add-in?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx-webparts, authorization, microsoft-graph

I have a set of graph queries that return the email addresses for my Office 365 Group members who are also the members of my connected SharePoint Team Site.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=startswith(displayName,'<group name>')
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/,<group id>/members?$select=givenName,surname,mail
```

I'd like to provide users that capability in a SharePoint Online tenant.

How can I do that with a SharePoint Framework web part wrapped in an add-in? My tenant admin has a process for approving add-ins to the App Store. I'm not sure which permissions I need to request and if the authentication and authorization of the current user carries through from an SPFx web part via an add-in.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442533/229910

Comment: Thanks, Mike. That is a similar question. This one is more specific to a SharePoint Framework web part and the Microsoft Graph API. That question asks about JavaScript on a page and it's not clear if Office Graph access from the search REST API is sufficient for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to connect to Graph API in SPFx environment and mostly failed. But now SPFx has `GraphHttpClient` available, which is still in development phase but can able to read groups. You can have a look at that.

Also, I found an angular based library `ADAL` available in npm as well, which can interact with Groups, Outlook, Calendar etc. You can add adal angular to your SPFx project using `npm i adal-angular@1.0.12`. Make sure you use version 1.0.12 only as the latest version is not working with SPFx.

Also take a look at [this post](http://www.vrdmn.com/2017/06/access-microsoft-graph-from-classic.html), which explains more about using Graph.

Comment: I found another good reference for GraphHttpClient at http://www.techmikael.com/2017/06/accessing-microsoft-graph-resources.html